# What is the best way to view all Javascript code generated or linked for a page?

Tags: javascript

For Javascript code that is linked or generated, what is the best way to view all of them?

Examples are like the Google AdSense or Analytics code, such as

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-xxxxxxxxx";
  [...]
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

I usually use Firefox's add-on Web Developer -> Information -> View Javascript.  Are there other ways too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) hands down the best web development tool there is.

Firebug lets you very quickly and easily see all of the javascript used on a page, as well as CSS, HTML, and even monitoring network requests.

You may also be interested in [Javascript Deobfuscator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10345). Despite it's name, it's actual much better than just a deobfuscator.

Comment: i only use Web Developer to view it before.  How is that done on Firebug?  thanks.

Comment: install the extension and click on the icon in the lower left (or press F12) to open the firebug panel. From there you can choose what to monitor and look at the details of each on the tabs

Comment: is it the Script tab?  I don't see all the resultant script there but just the link...

Comment: Once the script tab is active, there will be a file picker drop down menu (it usually renders just above the script tab itself)

Answer (score 2):

Does [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843) do what you need?

Comment: Firebug does *everything* you need.

Comment: @annakata, eh, not quite. It does not show HTTP requests to favicon.ico, which are always issues by the browser. Anyway, nitpicking :).

Comment: maybe Firebug cannot do this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949624  not a big deal, but can be nice to have.