# Is there any way to see the font loaded for a website?

Tags: css, fonts, firebug, web-inspector

[This question has already been asked four years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949624/can-firebug-or-any-tool-inspect-the-element-and-actually-tell-which-font-is-bein), but I just want to see if something new technically has arised:

In the css declaration block I can read out the font-families specified, but those names could represent anything.

**Is there any technique to *see* the font used for a element, particularly custom web fonts?**

Comment: @JohnConde Eh did you at all read my question? I already included the link you've provided.

Comment: If something has changed it can be answered in the old question. No need for a new question.

Comment: Let's say someone has answer today (but not four years ago), what's wrong with me bumping the question? What alternatives are there? Cause I don't know of any other way to re-actualize an old problem.

Comment: Heya, you can get attention for old questions by adding a bounty, there's even a specific bounty reason for it ("needs up to date answer").

Answer (score 1):

you can also use chrome developer tool's inspect element to check the font loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Does WhatTheFont's Chrome app do what you want?
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en

As you hover over live text on the web page, it looks into the css and tells you what font family is being used.